# Display Item Label for drop down list, radio button, many check box and boolean check box instead of item value

Tags: jsf-2

I am working on a customer profile page that has various elements viz. `h:selectOneMenu`, `h:selectOneRadio`, `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`, `h:selectManyCheckbox` which are populated using master values from the database using `List<MasterDTO>`. The elements display perfectly when the page is in edit mode. However when the page is changed to view mode, instead of the selected item label being displayed, the selected item value is displayed. E.g. Need to display `Single` as `Marital Status` in view mode, instead it displays `001`.

Please refer sample code below. I do not want to change the `List` object to something like a `Map<K,V>` across all the code. I am using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.4.2. Is there a solution for this?

**Select One Menu**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="marital_status" style="width:178px;"
    rendered="#{customerProfileBean.editMode}"
    value="#{customerProfileBean.marital_status}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="--- Select ---" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{customerProfileBean.maritalStatusList}"
        var="mst" itemLabel="#{mst.valueName}" itemValue="#{mst.valueCode}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText rendered="#{not customerProfileBean.editMode}"
    value="#{customerProfileBean.marital_status}" />
```

**Select Many Check Box**

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="loanTypes" styleClass="selectOptionSpace"
    rendered="#{customerProfileBean.editMode}"
    value="#{customerProfileBean.loanTypes}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{customerProfileBean.creditFacList}"
        var="mst" itemLabel="#{mst.valueName}" itemValue="#{mst.valueCode}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
<h:outputText rendered="#{not customerProfileBean.editMode}"
    value="#{customerProfileBean.custLoanType}" />
```

Comment: That's not primefaces related. You just use jsf in your example. Primefaces would be p:selectOneMenu and p:selectManyCheckbox. Your primefaces version is totally outdated btw. The newest community version is 6.0.

Comment: You seem to have the 'labels' in the valueName properties of the items in maritalStatusList. So a simple java side method to show this based on the  marital_status value  would solve your problem... effectively not even jsf relatead...

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the `jsf` controls with the primefaces controls viz. `p:selectOneMenu` and `p:selectManyCheckbox` which fixed the problem of displaying value instead of code.